# How do I use Chrome's history API to search for visits matching a given URL?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to write a little chrome extension that searches the history for recent visits a particular site and does something with it. I'm a bit dismayed that it would seem there is no way to search Chrome's history based on URLs.

The only API that I find, at http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/history.html, lists only one search function, with a text area that does a full-text search on the *contents* of visited pages. Searching for http://sitename does not return any HistoryItems for that site, and simply 'sitename' returns irrelevant results that *mention* the site in question.

So something like this returns no results:

```
chrome.history.search({text: 'http://stackoverflow.com', maxResults:10}, function(results) { console.log(results) })
```

But something like this does, but includes numerous results from other domains, and indeed, results that do not contain the words 'stackoverflow.com', but contain words similar to them:

```
chrome.history.search({text: 'stackoverflow.com', maxResults:10}, function(results) { console.log(results) })
```

Is this really all there is? Is there really no way for me to, for example, ask the chrome history service 'tell me the last 10 pages visisted on stackoverflow.com'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently no way to do this. History queries end up being handled by [TextDatabase::GetTextMatches](http://www.google.com/codesearch#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/chrome/browser/history/text_database.cc&l=305), and that offers no way to search over the URL only. Your best bet is to filter down the results to ones where the URL actually matches. See [processHistoryItems](https://github.com/mihaip/theres-a-web-app-for-that/blob/master/extension/options.html#L216) in an extension of mine for an example of that.

Comment: I guess even a 'too bad' gets a checkmark sometimes. How's the performance on your processHistoryItems function? Is the history indexed such that scanning it all like that is performant?

Comment: You can see it for yourself by installing the extension frmo https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ohmcjnlhiaobipnkdonkcpomgkpgfdch (the page that's displayed when first installed uses processHistoryItems). On my machine, it takes a couple of seconds to scan through the entire database.

Comment: I decided to limit mine to the last month and it works instantly, as far as humans are concerned. I would not have dared try it, so thanks for the response :)